# Password Regular expression validation?

Tags: javascript, html

I got 2 password fields called password and confirm password. I managed to validate it to make sure that the passwords must match. However, I do not know how to add regular expressions to  the password field to allow it 6 characters long, containing at least an uppercase and a number.

This is the javascript i got so far

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function validatepw() {
  if ( document.register.user_password.value != document.register.user_password_confirm.value)
    {
    alert('Passwords did not match!');
        return false;
        }else{
        document.register.submit();
        return true;
    }
    }
</script>
```

and this is my form

```
<form name="register" action="signup.php" onsubmit="return validate_reg()" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >

<table width="600" border="0">
<tr><td width="210" height="45">Username*:</td><td>
<input type="text" size="40" name="userUsername" id="user_username" /></td></tr>
<tr><td width="210" height="45">Password*:</td><td>
<input type="password" size="40" name="userPassword" id="user_password"/></td></tr> 
    <tr><td width="210" height="45">Re-type Password:</td><td>
<input type="password" size="40" name="userPasswordConfirm" 
id="user_password_confirm" onchange="javascript:validatepw()"/></td></tr>
</table>
<center><input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="register"></center>    
</form>
```

Can anyone show how to apply the regular expression of 6 characters, an uppercase and a number to the password field. I have searched a lot and cant find anything that works with what i already got.

Comment: http://regexlib.com/ Library of regular expressions, maybe you can find one here

Comment: It's probably a bad idea to submit the form from the `change` event of a single field. It's also not necessary to use `javascript:` for event handler attributes. (And inline event handlers are a little ugly as well.)

Comment: A related tip: it's bad practice to enforce password validation rules without telling users in advance what those rules are, in plain english, before they type anything.

Answer (score 7):

There's no need to try to squeeze all of this into one regex.

```
password.match(/[A-Z]/) && password.match(/[0-9]/) && (password.length >= 6)
```

Comment: What is the easiest way to squeeze that into my javascript?

Comment: What's wrong with a single RegExp? `/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6}/`

Comment: @RobW Searing pain of the eyes? The fact it's several times harder to tell what it does?

Comment: Sorry I am totally new to javascript. I know that single regExp that you mentioned is found all over the internet but they don't say how to implement it to the form

Comment: @munue Your question was confusingly phrased. Also, you need to add another `if` just like the one you already have in `validatepw()` for the new check.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can use a single regex for this if you'd like to:

```
var isValid = /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}/.test(password)
```

(Lookahead for at least one digit, lookahead for at least one letter, then match anything, 6 or more times)